# Can deep learning be done with GPUs other than Nvidia's GPUs?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm planning to buy a GPU and I have been presented with multiple options. There some GPUs which are not Nvidia's product but have better performances than their Nvidia's equivalent in terms of price. My question now is, if I buy, say, an ASUS GPU, can use it for deep learning and exploit tensorflow gpu-based drivers with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. You just have to choose a framework that supports rocm, opencl or something like that instead of cuda. Tensorflow can be compiled with rocm support but I have not used it. Also you can check here: https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/tensorflow-upstream

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do deep learning on any GPU/CPU. Deep learning essentually is just matrix multiplication and the actuation function. Here OpenCL offers great compatibility and efficiency across all hardware, including AMD/Intel/ARM/Nvidia GPUs/CPUs.

However this may not be as fast, because Nvidia-GPUs have special hardware ("Tensor Cores") to vastly accelerate matrix multiplication in reduced 16-bit (FP16), 19-bit (TF32) of 64-bit (FP64) floating-point precision.
AMD has Tensor Cores for FP32 on the CDNA MI100 GPU.